# ExtJS and JWplayer

Tags: extjs, jwplayer

I have an application in ExtJS that uses a JWplayer for reproduce some videos. But i'm experiencing some weird bugs.

When the page loads it seems that the JWPlayer won't load and then I receive a black line where the player should be displayed.

I am loading the jwplayer inside a extjs panel.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: I have no experience with ExtJS. Is it possible to provide a link to your application so I can replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a draggable floating panel with an instance of JW Player inside and it works just find.

Check it out, maybe you are doing something wrong there.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
            title: 'Testing JW Player',
            width: 480,
            height: 300,
            floating: true,
            draggable: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'testing'
            }],
            listeners: {
                afterrender : function(component) {
                    jwplayer('testing').setup({
                    file: "http://videos-jp.jwpsrv.com/zWLy8Jer/videos/HkauGhRi-1753142.mp4?77c801d752d5207784c49e7ed80fb953798fae0fcca03ecf79558491aa7db70fc9392eb19e958e847c3e486d709eab9f57d25c86934c4b6091bc427de8ab078578054aaba8384904c4762bd67442c3809470687047",
                    image: "http://demo.jwplayer.com/homepage/homepage_preroll.jpg"
                    });
                    }
                }
        });
    }
});
```

You can access my fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/blb

- JWPlayer is a nice library by the way, this was the first time I saw it, nice work.

Answer (score -1):

For those whom may have the same issue that I had.
I was placing the player in a panel but **I didn't set the height of the component**. Since the player takes a while to load I guess that the Extjs just see it as a common div with no size.